# Defining a variable/label to use with inline assembly JMP instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, namespaces, label

I a have function with inline assembly that has the following definition:

```
void __declspec(naked) func()
{
    __asm 
    {
        //...
        JMP [address]
        //...
    }
}
```

This address variable is known only at run time, at main I have:

```
int main()
{
    //...
    DWORD address = getAddress();
    func();
    //...
}
```

As like that, the code will not compile with the following error message:

> error C2094:  label 'address' was undefined

1. How can I work around this problem, knowing that I cannot pass address as a parameter to the `func()` function?
2. Could I define address in a namespace? Would it be good practice? Can namespaces be used to promote the scope of a variable (using this variable at diferent functions/scopes)?

Comment: As a general rule; *don't* use inline ASM in the first place.

Comment: Pass the address as a function arg; obviously a function can't access another function's local variables.

Answer (score 0):

you are in C++, the destructors must be called when you leave blocks having instances of classes in the stack, this will not be the case with your JMP, and I do not speak about the value of the stack pointer/frame

C++ have exceptions, use them, for instance give in argument the address of a function without argument to call in your assembly portion, and that function `throw` the exception you want, and place a `try-catch` at the destination you want to go